# Solucionar error 502 Bad Gateway en NGINX

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

Buen día

Como puedo solucionar el siguiente error en **NGINX**

> 502 Bad Gateway

En los logs aparece lo siguiente:

> [error] 15839#0: *3615 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer)
>   while reading response header from upstream, client

He realizado las configuraciones del siguiente link y aún persiste el error.

```
https://www.scalescale.com/tips/nginx/502-bad-gateway-error-using-nginx/
```

Gracias,

Comment: Cómo tienes configurado php-fpm? Seguro que está andando? Corre en un puerto específico o en un sock?

Comment: SI, el servicio esta corriendo, en el www.conf, tiene lo siguiente "listen = 127.0.0.1:9000"

Comment: y tienes el upstream seteado en la configuración de nginx?

Comment: No, upstream no tiene

Comment: Y cómo tienes el bloque fastcgi en el vhost de laravel? A lo mejor está en duro como  `fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;`

Comment: ` location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param   REMOTE_ADDR             $remote_addr;
        fastcgi_param   REMOTE_PORT             $remote_port;
        fastcgi_param   SERVER_ADDR             $server_addr;
        fastcgi_param   SERVER_PORT             $server_port;
        fastcgi_param   SERVER_NAME             $server_name;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }`

Comment: Y cómo te consta que php-fpm está corriendo? hiciste un `netstat`?

Comment: service php-fpm status.

Comment: Uso laravel, y solo da error en ciertas rutas cuando uso la libreria Maatwebsite para exportar a excel

Comment: En ese caso, no se me ocurre.

Comment: Hay muchas posibles causas https://airbrake.io/blog/http-errors/502-bad-gateway-error, si sólo tienes problemas con la la librería Maatwebsite, prueba otra que haga lo mismo.

Comment: El error 502 ocurre cuando el servidor destino no está a la escucha, sería bueno compartir el bloque de configuración del `server` o a menos el `location` en Nginx.